# Why was my question about inheritance deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, delete-reason

I asked https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/481/do-women-get-half-in-inheritance-than-men-do

This question stayed for quite some time but then some users closed it and I finally a moderator deleted the question altogether. I wonder, if this is such a complicated question that cannot be answered. I have pointed out a clear case where I know something and I have heard something else. I needed clarification there? My question is why was this question *deleted*. While close was by community, I deletion was by moderator.

I also believe, this site is for expert so if you dont know the answer, someone else might have. Why would someone close and delete this question and I have asked an extremely important question. I have brother and sister and want to know the answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The question was closed, it was not a good fit for this site and had no votes.

Hadn't it been deleted by a moderator [Community](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/-1) would have [deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/221866) it. Take [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12724/3487) question for instance.

I think the question needs some editing love and have its core question explicitly stated and then I certainly think it should be undeleted and reopened. As is, it appear to be bit broad and slightly unclear.

Comment: My question had three answers so community would not auto-delete it. More importantly it is a question. I argued with goldsuedo, people generally here are not interested in real Islamic question but tend to get involved in controversial question. By deleting real questions, we are promoting controversial questions as result.

Comment: @muslim1 I suggest instead of getting dragged into a discussion on controversies edit the question out and flag it for mod to undelete.

Comment: @mods are not even interested in answering questions on meta. Not sure if edit would help.

Comment: @muslim1 If you're unwilling to edit then similarly the modes would be unwilling to undeleted/answer etc.

Comment: @BleedingFingers to be fair, i'd probably be unwilling to undelete it anyway.  one would need to present a compelling argument why the editing/flagging/undeleting route (which would also require purging obsolete comments and deleting obsolete answers) is in any way useful for a question that's been off the site for over a year.  compared to just asking a new clear question which can be posted at any time with zero moderator intervention, where none of that would need to be done at all.